# Animate FAB icon dynamically in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, translation, floating-action-button

I am trying to implement something like a Google Calendar Floating Action Button where when you press it the `+` icon changes to a `Calendar` icon and when pressed back it changes back to `+`.

I have been able to make changes using `setImageDrawable` where I can handle the functionality such that initially the icon is `+` and when I open the FAB I use the `setImageDrawable` to set the new icon I want and when the user closes the FAB I again use the `setImageDrawable` to show the `+` icon.

It seems to be working fine but is not exactly what I want. As stated above I want it to be something like a Calendar app so that there is an animation. Does anybody have idea about how to go about this? Any help would be appreicated.

[Google Calendar FAB Video for reference](https://youtube.com/shorts/lRFiJOgN5kE?feature=share)

[My Current FAB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luSFVFDMVUU)

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're using Jetpack Compose for their UI, and it's pretty easy to do view animations/transitions that way. I'm not sure how open you are to migrating your UI to Compose, but that's my suggestion.

Comment: But if you want to keep using the "old" view architecture, you'll need to set up an animation for rotating the icon inside the FAB, and after the rotation finishes, change the icon